# Is it possible to use BCH formula on Riemannian exp, or just for a 'good' approximation?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Given 3 points A, B, C on a Riemannian manifold, if we already have the geodesics between A->B  and A->C (fully determined by their correspondent initial directions v0(A->B) and v0(A->C)),  is it possible to compute or approximate the geodesic between B and C based on V0(A->B) and v0(A->C)?  I know in general BCH formula can not work since the geodesic is different from the Lie exp. In my case, the Riemannian manifold is a Lie group with a right-invariant (not bi-invariant unfortunately) Reimannian metric. Can this help to approximate the v0(B->C) using the BCH formula?

If the Riemannian manifold is the volume preserving diffeomorphism group SDiff(M) as in the ideal incompressible fluid, can the BCH trick be applied?